# how to connect admin-on-rest main component to redux-store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

In admin-on-rest I want to save property "screen mode" (mobile or desktop) in redux-store. I wrote action and reducer for this task:

```
///action
export const SET_SCREEN_MODE = 'SET_SCREEN_MODE'

export default  (mode) => ({
  type: SET_SCREEN_MODE,
  mode: mode
});


///reducer

import { SET_SCREEN_MODE } from './changeScreenModeAction';

export default (previousState = 'screen', { type, mode }) => {
    if (type === SET_SCREEN_MODE) {
        return mode
    }
    return previousState;
}
```

Problem is that I need to call action to update state in My main app-component:

```
import changeScreenModeAction from './changeScreenModeAction'
...
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount = () => {
        const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        const mode = this.checkMode(windowWidth);
        if (this.state.screenMode != mode) {
          this.props.changeScreenMode(mode)
        }
}
...
    render() {
        return (
            <Admin
              customReducers={customReducers}
              restClient={restClient}
            >
           ...my Resources
            </Admin>
        );
    }
 }
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   changeScreenMode: changeScreenModeAction
 })

 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

But, of course, I get error that redux-connect function didn't find provider in this context.

Is there only one method to do such  things - https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html, or, maybe I have more simple way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first of all you should use the `Responsive` component for rendering views for different targets. Your initial idea will not respond to screensize changes.

For your use case, it's best to create a custom `startupSaga` and pass it the `customSaga` prop of `Admin` or create a custom `Layout` and pass it to the `appLayout` prop of `Admin`.